# Flash object not loading in older versions of IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to load a flash object and I am having a hard time getting it to work in ie6,ie7, and ie8. The flash object is a button for an uploader. The flash object loads in firefox, chrome, safari, opera, and ie9 fine. I have searched google for answers and I have not been able to fix it. Here is the code that i used to load the flash object (it has changed various times with no luck in ie6-ie8)

```
                            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../flash/s3_upload.swf" codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="266" height="46" id="s3_swf_1" style="visibility: visible; ">
                                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                                <param name="menu" value="false" />
                                <param name="quality" value="low" />
                                <embed src= "../flash/s3_upload.swf" quality="low" width="266" height="46" id="s3_swf_1" wmode="transparent" menu="false" style="visibility: visible" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" />
                        </object>
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Flash. Use it to your hearts content. Just make sure to use fallbacks if you need to target platforms or user agents that lack support for Flash. That's the same attitude that you need to have towards transparent PNG images, HTML5 video (or HTML5 anything), javascript and any other feature for which there is no ubiquitous support.

Comment: Sorry - I'm deleting my previous comment because it's sujective and argumentative.  I should know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your SWF in your HTML page. SWFObject relies on Javascript, but will make sure that the correct version of the Flash Player is installed, as well as generate the proper embed object for the user's particular browser.

I'm not sure what's causing this particular issue, but it's likely that using SWFObject will solve your problem.

Comment: I am using the plugin located here: https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin/

it has a built in custom swfobject code that initializes when the page is loaded.

It uses the id = s3_swf_1 to initialize it.

Comment: The code from your original post is HTML and not related to SWFObject. Are you actually using SWFObject and not the code above, or are you perhaps using both? If you're using SWFObject, try removing the above HTML, or wrapping it in <noscript> tags.

Comment: I'm an idiot, i got it working. I should have put the id in a div instead of an object with all the flash settings. If you couldn't tell, I'm new to web development, started last month. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `param name="movie" value="dc10_no_loop.swf">`.